# Unusual Object Destructuring after useEffect function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, javascript-objects

I have faced a very weird form of object destructing in react.js, here is my problem:
To being with, this useEffect function is used to initialize the `rooms` variable.

```
const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
  const _auth = getAuth(app);
  const [_user, loading] = useAuthState(_auth);
  let currentUserUID = "";

  const router = useRouter();
  const result = router.query;
  console.log(result);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (loading) return;
      console.log("Useffect has ran");
      currentUserUID = _user.uid;
      console.log(currentUserUID);
      let roomRef = collection(db, currentUserUID.toString());
      const data = query(roomRef, where(documentId(), "==", result.roomID));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(data);
      console.log(querySnapshot);
      const docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        data.id = doc.id;
        return data;
      });
      console.log(docs);
      setRooms(docs);
    })();
  }, [loading]);
```

Since this is a very specific call, it returns an array with only one element, which is an object. For the sake of this post, I am taking an array that has this object with values filled in it. Following is the rooms array after the useEffect function:

```
rooms  = [{
  arrival: '12-12-1212',
  checkedIn: false,
  departure: '13-13-1313',
  guests: {
    nameOfSecondaryGuests: [],
    numberOfGuests: 3,
    primaryGuestInfo: {
      DOB: '19-19-1919',
      age: 0,
      email: 'Rob@email.com',
      firstName: 'Rob',
      lastName: 'Bor'
    },
    id: "room82",
    nights: 12,
    price: 12825,
    roomNumber: 82,
    secondaryRoomsBooked: []
  }
}]
```

Now the problem arises when I try to access the data from this `rooms` array. When I try to run the following code after the useEffect function, I get a `singular_room.guests.primaryGuestInfo.firstName` is undefined, even though the singular_room object does have all the data I just tried to access.

For reference:

```
  const singular_room = rooms[0];
  console.log(singular_room.guests.primaryGuestInfo.firstName)
```

However, when I map through the `rooms` array and try to access the same fields, I am able to get an output. Here is my Map code:

```
rooms.map((room) => {
                console.log(room.guests.primaryGuestInfo.firstName)
              })
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening or how can I direct access the data from the object using the first method? Thanks.

Comment: I think your question isn't related to React it's about arrays but did you tried to call the index as `String` like  `room['0']` or did you tried to check the index of room in the console to check it's type `console.log(room)` please attach screenshot of your array in the console that might be useful to find a solution

Comment: @MahmoudY3c I tried keeping the index as a string and it did not work, however, here is the screenshot of the `console.log(room)`   [image](https://imgur.com/yFEi6Gv)

Comment: I meant to console `rooms` not `room` in the map

Comment: I need you to attach screen for your array before doing anything on it

Comment: @MahmoudY3c here: [console.log screenshot](https://imgur.com/rIaSRwm)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `loading` for truthiness before manipulating the data.

```js
loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <>...</>
```

Comment: This did not seem to solve the problem. Thanks for the help though!